# An Unix networking programming puzzles me:what does read function return on earth in this situation?

Tags: unix, tcp, network-programming

Assuming that the client and server send packets according to the order of sequence as shown in the figure. 
   The client sends “hello” and prints the "hello" message on the screen echoed by the server successfully. Then it sends "hello" again to the server after the server process was killed and FIN was arrived. The server responds to the client with an RST and the RST reaches the client,too. Then if the client begins to block on a read operation, why it returns 0 due to the FIN instead of -1 because the RST? In the 《Effective TCP/IP programming》, it tells us that the core will return ECONNRESET error and read should return -1. 
My operating system is Ubuntu 12.10. Is it related with the operating system? Please tell me some TCP’s details on this implementation. Thanks in advance.
[image]

(1)The client program is:

```
#include "BaseHeader.h"

#define MSGLENDTH 5

void sigHandler(int signo)
{
    printf("SIGPIPE\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
if(argc != 3)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "the number of argument is wrong");

int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in peer;

setAddress(argv[1] , argv[2] , &peer , "tcp");

struct sigaction newact;
newact.sa_handler = &sigHandler;
sigemptyset(&newact.sa_mask);
newact.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGPIPE , &newact , NULL);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

if(sockfd < 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "create socket error");

int ret = connect(sockfd , (struct sockaddr*)&peer , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if(ret != 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "connect error");

char buf[100];
int len;

while( fgets(buf , sizeof(buf) , stdin) != NULL)
{
    len = strlen(buf);
    ret = write(sockfd , buf , len - 1);

    if(ret != MSGLENDTH)
        PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "write error");

    sleep(5);
    ret = read(sockfd , buf , sizeof(buf));

    if(ret < 0)
        PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "read error");

    else if(ret == 0)
        PrintError(-1 , 0 , AT , "server terminated");

    else
        fputs(buf , stdout);

}
return 0;
}
```

(2) The server program is that:

```
#include "BaseHeader.h"

#define LISTENQ 1024
#define BUFSIZE 5

int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
char* hostname;
char* servicename;

struct sockaddr_in local;
struct sockaddr_in peer;

if(argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "the number of argument is wrong");

if(argc == 2)
{
    hostname =  NULL;
    servicename = argv[1];
}

else
{
    hostname = argv[1];
    servicename = argv[2];
}

setAddress(hostname , servicename , &local , "tcp");

int listenfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

if(listenfd < 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "create socket error");

int const on = 1;
if( setsockopt(listenfd , SOL_SOCKET , SO_REUSEADDR , &on , sizeof(on) ) )
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "set socket option error");

int ret = bind(listenfd , (struct sockaddr*)&local , sizeof(sockaddr_in));

if(ret != 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "bind error");

ret = listen(listenfd , LISTENQ);

if(ret != 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "listen error");

int connfd = accept(listenfd , NULL , NULL);

if(connfd < 0)
    PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "accept error");

char recvbuf[BUFSIZE + 1];
recvbuf[BUFSIZE] = '\0';

while(1)
{
    sleep(5);
    ret = read(connfd , recvbuf , (sizeof(recvbuf) - 1) );

    if(ret != BUFSIZE)
        PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "read error");

    ret = write(connfd , recvbuf , strlen(recvbuf));

    if(ret != BUFSIZE)
        PrintError(-1 , errno , AT , "write error");
}
return 0;
}
```

**The related text in the 《Effective TCP/IP Programming》 is shown blow:**
 [image]

Comment: I've seen this same question before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22503882/207421) and I asked a question about it too. Please post the exact text from the book that you claim makes this statement.

Comment: You have correctly received everything from the server, so `read()` has no reason to fail. But you couldn't `write()` everything, so `close()` should fail.

Comment: I don't understand what you said, ninjalj. When the client reads second times in this program, I think a FIN and a RST segments have reached the client. Tcpdump also shows that in the figure. And i don't call close function at all.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that 'the client is blocked in the call to `fgets,` and TCP has no way of notifying the client that it has received an EOF (the FIN) from the other side' is blatantly incorrect. That's what the return value of zero from `recv()` and friends is *for*. The `recv()` or `read()` or whatever will return zero, `fgets()` will return null, and there you are, the client has been notified.

However it is probably open to TCP to override the existing FIN with the RST, and I've seen that happen within the localhost.

What's the full name and citation of this erroneous text?

Comment: On the page 74th of 《Effective TCP/IP Programming》. The tip 9:Realize That TCP is Reliable Protocol,Not an Infallible Protocol.

Comment: BTW, the OP's `fgets()` reads _stdin_, not the socket, the point of the text being that the error will be noticed on the next call to the socket (which is incorrect, `read()` should return the EOF, and the error shouldn't be noticed until the next `write()/close()`).

Comment: read() should return the EOF, but the error will be noticed by the next write() not close()

Comment: @TonyYu: if there is no next `write()`, it will be returned on `close()`, which you should call and check the return value of to ensure everything has been transmitted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A literal reading of POSIX would prohibit returning an error in `recv()/read()` if the other end has properly shutdown (with no data pending/lost, no RST before the FIN, having sent a FIN, ...)(*emphasis added*):

> Upon  successful  completion, recv() shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0. **Otherwise**, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.

You will notice the write error on your next call to `send()/write()`<sup>1</sup>, or on your next call to `close()` (which is why you should *always* call `close()`, and *check* its return value).

<sup>1</sup> usually you will not notice it in the call that originates the failed message, since sending a message and receiving a RST takes some time, and `send()/write()` will return as soon as it has copied the message in the send buffer, and possibly transmitted it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. Do you have some official material or websites for my reference?